# How to build a more efficient voltage divider

Tags: circuit-design, voltage-divider

I have a voltage monitor built into a dashboard that I would like to use, which monitors voltages between 10-30v and draws about 15mA - I want to be able to monitor voltages in the 40-60v range instead, so I figured I would build a voltage divider and just know that I need to double the output of the display. 
I am asking for suggestions as far as what would be the best way to do this thus far I have considered:

Burning many watts of power just using a resistor divider with relatively low value / high wattage resistors.

Using an adjustable linear regulator and somehow tie the input to the reference?

Some sort of op-amp where I have the input divided and compared to the output, but I don't really know what kind of Op-amp to use

Comment: "Burning many watts of power just using a resistor divider with relatively low value / high wattage resistors. " -- Why _relatively_ low value?

Comment: You need to supply the datasheet for the "voltage monitor". It really depends on the input impedance. If this is a 2-wire voltmeter, you can replace it with a 3-wire and a voltage regulator to supply the meter.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Because I won't get an accurate voltage AND 15mA if I use anything relatively high..

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It's a unit that's basically built into a dash and I don't want to take it apart since I would never be able to get it back in properly, otherwise I fully agree with you in that would be a viable method

Comment: use relatively high and buffer that with an op-amp.

Comment: @HarrySvensson  That's what I was thinking with the last sentence.. but what sort of op-amp do I want? they all seem to be made for fast switching, which is not anything I care about.. yes, I need it to support 60v, but does it need to be RTR? with "high buffering", are they still stable? do I need one that can handle capacitance? etc.

Comment: I'll let someone else answer this, you're definitely over thinking things / over complicating.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way  is to use a a compensated (or not) attenuator and instrumentation amplifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc7Rmb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you need very high impedance, then a FET or JFET input stage is needed, else you can use a bipolar instrumentation amplifier.